# What should `foo.template bar()` do when there's both a template and a non-template overload?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

A coworker shared this code with me:

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:19,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:19,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:19,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:19,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++void+foo()+%7Bstd::cout+%3C%3C+%221%5Cn%22%3B%7D%0A%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T+%3D+int%3E%0A++++void+foo()+%7Bstd::cout+%3C%3C+%222%5Cn%22%3B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++A+x%3B%0A++++x.template+foo()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:43.28981723237598,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:29.623619985624018,l:%274%27,m:49.21700223713646,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50.78299776286354,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:56.71018276762404,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void foo() {std::cout << "1\n";}
    
    template <typename T = int>
    void foo() {std::cout << "2\n";}
};

int main()
{
    A x;
    x.template foo();
}
```

GCC prints `1`, Clang prints `2`, and MSVC complains about missing template arguments.

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: @icaptan I don't want a C++20 tag because there are no C++20-specific features here.

Comment: you're right. I replaced C++20 by C++11, the call x.template foo() is C++11 specific.

Comment: @icaptan I dunno. On one hand yes, but on the other hand [the standard rules are constantly changing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html), and I don't want people to assume that I'm targeting an outdated standard. I'm asking about the latest standard (which is implied by having no tag).

Comment: not a big deal, it's your question :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[[temp.names]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.names#5) says that a name prefixed by `template` must be a *template-id*, meaning that it must have a template argument list. (Or it can refer to a class/alias template without template argument list, but this [is deprecated in the current draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/depr.template.template) as a result of [P1787R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) authored by @DavisHerring.)

There is even an example almost identical to yours under it, identifying your use of `template` as ill-formed.

The requirement and example comes from [CWG defect report 96](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#96), in which the possible ambiguity without the requirement is considered.

Open GCC bug report for this is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55588). I was not able to find a Clang bug report, but searching for it isn't that easy. Its [implementation status page for defect reports](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) however does list the defect report as unimplemented.

Comment: C++ has become a liability.  Even the compiler makers can't keep up anymore.

Comment: Reported a bug to Clang: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53095

Comment: @Jellyboy I would'nt use this core issue as an example for that claim, though. CWG96 is over two decades old, and its resolution over a decade old; I'd argue that it's rather that the priority of this particular issue has intentionally been set to extremely low by compiler vendors. Both [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-dr-status.html) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) lists core issue 96 as not (yet) implemented.

Comment: @dfrib you just made my point Sir

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm not entirely sure how Clang is managed. Maybe nobody looks at the DR page, and without a bug report, nobody would remember about this issue. Or I could be wrong, and then the ticket is indeed noise.

Comment: @dfrib _I'd argue that it's rather that the priority of this particular issue has intentionally been set to extremely low_ And prolly because its resolution doesn't affect the acceptance of valid code, only rejection of invalid.

Answer (score 16):

**MSVC** is correct to reject this: the standard has just this as [an example](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#5.example-1).  The `template` parser guide *is* allowed before the qualified name of a class or alias template without template arguments, but this is only for compatibility with implementations that needlessly require it for template template arguments and is now deprecated.